# How to know that QSqlQuery::bindValue call was correct

Tags: sql, qt

Is there any possibility to know QSqlQuery::bindValue call is ok?

The functions returns void and I wonder why? At least the absence of the required place-holder should be reported (ihmo) as an error.

Maybe there is another possibility to check, that binding is correct?

Comment: how do you mean the call is correct? bind value will just be replacing a place holder with the value you bind to it? you can use `lastError().text()` to get back the SQL error if thats what your asking

Comment: alternatively you could use `boundValue()` and pass the placeholder or position to it, this returns the bound value which you could then check?

Comment: On 1st comment: I wonder, why bindValue doesn't check, if the place-holder is in the query, which was provided earlier by prepare.

Comment: To the second comment: OK, good point! In my code the bindValue are called by auto-generated / script code. I was neither sure, if all place-holders were set, no if there is an error in placeholder-name. getting all required placeholders from sql and checking them with boundValue looks like a solution.

Comment: ok cool ill add as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bindValue() and pass the placeholder name or the position and it will return the value that has been bound, so you will be able to check if values have bound correctly. Alternatively use boundValues() which will return a map of all the keys and values:

Sample from Qt Docs for `boundValues()`

```
QMapIterator<QString, QVariant> i(query.boundValues());
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    cout << i.key().toUtf8().data() << ": "
         << i.value().toString().toUtf8().data() << endl;
}
```

Comment: boundValues() seems to be a good option for "simple" query. But sometimes it doesn't work good - for example if you have one parameter used several times in your query (then you bind it once but boundValues() returns several values)